# record being deleted without confirmation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootbox dialogs for confirming before deleting records.

here is my jQuery script for confirmation before deleting record.

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" id="deleteContent" title="Delete">delete</a>

$('#deletec').click(function (e) {
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: "you data is save",
        title: "Custom title",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Success!",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function () {
                    Example.show("great you save it");
                }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Danger!",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function () {
                    Example.show("record deleted!");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

it is showing correct dialog but the record being deleted without taking confirmation, can anyone please tell me how can i prevent deletion of record without confirmation ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code that is making the deletion?

Comment: sounds like you are calling the delete code at the same time as the dialog instead of putting the delete call in the danger callback.

Comment: @epascarello - that's just a delete query. `DELETE content FROM content WHERE ID = id`

Comment: Is the link going to the server causing that to happen? And doing DELETES with a get request is a bad idea.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - actually I am new to this.. I am just bounding the click function around the dialog incase delete button click it must display dialog and take confirmation

Comment: that link takes the request to the server side for deleting.... before i have tried this it works fine but it doesn't looks good ` $('#deleteContent').click(function(e){
  var res = window.confirm('are you sure you wanna delete this content?');
  if(res == false){
   e.preventDefault();
  };
 }); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do what you want because the modal dialog that you are using has no way of pausing the click action. You would need to have to cancel the click action and than make that call.

One way is just to unbind click and call it again

```
$('#deleteContent').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: "you data is save",
        title: "Custom title",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Success!",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function () {
                    Example.show("great you save it");
                }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Danger!",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function () {                        
                    Example.show("record deleted!");
                    $('#deleteContent').off("click")[0].click();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As I said in my comments above, making a delete request with a get is a BAD idea. If a user has a plugin that prefetches pages, say goodbye to all your data in the database.

---

What happens in the code

1. `e.preventDefault();`  Cancels the click event so it will not go to the server
2. `$('#deleteContent').off("click")`  //removes the click event so it will not be called again
3. `[0].click()`  //selects the DOM element and calls the click event to trigger the navigation

Comment: now when i click btn-danger for deleting the records not being deleted... :(

Comment: I put on the wrong one...switching the code...  `$('#deleteContent').off("click")[0].click();`

Comment: Oh yeah i fixed that already.... Thanks a lot... this is appreciating...  will please tell about that not using delete get with a request ?

Comment: Added brief explanation above

Comment: i have multiple records in list and it prompting this dialog on only one record could you please tell me what i need to have ?